# Proving that the cover time for graph is exponential in the worst case

Tags: algorithms, graphs, random-walks

How can I prove that the cover time for a directed graph $G$ can be exponential in the size of $G$?

The cover time is the expected length of a random walk that visits all vertices.

Comment: What is the "cover time"?

Comment: I think cover time means the expected number of steps taken by a random walk to visit every vertex.

Comment: You also have to assume that the graph is strongly connected.

Answer (score 4):

You do it in two steps:

1. First you think of a graph which you can expect to be difficult.
2. Then you prove your suspicion.

Let's start with the first step - do you have any graph in mind?

Comment: To a novice, it might not be at all obvious that when you say “think of a graph”, you really mean “for all $n$ [or at least an infinite number of integers $n$], think of a graph of size $n$” and “prove your suspicion” involves computing the cover size in terms of $n$ and finding an expression that is exponential in $n$. A hint that isn't even didactic is really not useful.

Comment: @Gilles Why don't you add your own answer, then?

Answer (score 1):

If the digraph is not strongly connected, then the cover time is infinite, so let's assume the digraph is strongly connected. Here is an example:
Consider $n>2$ vertices  $v_1,\ldots,v_n$, with a directed edge from $v_i$ to $v_{i+1}$ for $i=1,\ldots,n-1$ and a directed edge from $v_j$ to $v_1$ for $j=2,\ldots,n$.
Starting from $v_1$, the number of visits to $v_1$ before reaching $v_n$ has a geometric distribution with parameter $2^{2-n}$, so the expected hitting time from $v_1$ to $v_n$ (which is a lower bound for the cover time) is at least $2^{n-2}.$